# Does a documentFragment element reset itself?

Tags: javascript

This is a strange behavior I noticed.  I did not reset a document but immediately used it after I had appended it, and the previous elements it contained were not there.

Should I be clearing it as such?

```
frag_inner = '';
```

Are there side-effects I'm not aware of?

```
frag_outer = NS.createDocumentFragment();
frag_inner = NS.createDocumentFragment();

NS.eachIndex(obj, function(val) {

    // fragment element - inner

    // image element

    val.view_picture = (val.picture === '0') ? this.A.images + 'generic_large.jpg' :
            this.A.pictures + val.h_file  + '-2.jpg';
    img_element = $A.createElement('img');
    img_element.className = 'tweet';
    img_element.src = val.view_picture;
    frag_inner.appendChild(img_element);

    // link element

    link_element = $A.createElement('a');
    link_element.className = 'tweet';
    link_element.innerHTML = val.name + ' posted ' +
            this.prettyTime(val.time) + '<br>';
    frag_inner.appendChild(link_element);

    // paragraph element

    par_element = $A.createElement('p');
    par_element.className = 'tweet';
    par_element.innerHTML = val.tweet;
    frag_inner.appendChild(par_element);

    // div element

    div_element = $A.createElement('div');
    div_element.className = 'tweet';
    div_element.appendChild(frag_inner);

    // append the div which is now populated

    frag_outer.appendChild(div_element);

}, this);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's actually the expected behaviour, as...

1) it's a well-known feature of `Node.appendChild` to move existing Nodes. As said in the docs ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild))...

> [Node.appendChild]... adds a node to the end of the list of children of a specified
>   parent node. If the node already exists it is removed from current
>   parent node, then added to new parent node.

2) when you append `documentFragment`, you actually append all its children ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) again):

> Various other methods can take a document fragment as an argument
>   (e.g., any Node interface methods such as Node.appendChild and
>   Node.insertBefore), in which case the children of the fragment are
>   appended or inserted, not the fragment itself.

The point is, when you do someNode.append(documentFragment), you remove all its children from it, then append them to `someNode`. That's why `documentFragment` is empty as result.

---

Note that when you do this...

```
frag_inner = '';
```

... you're not clearing the documentFragment stored in this variable - you store a new value (an empty string, obviously) in it instead. The very first attempt to work with it as with documentFragment should result in something like `TypeError: Object has no method 'appendChild'`.

Comment: well I guess that is "normal" behavior, when you append the documentFragment to the DOM, it's contents are removed.  Good thing I did not want to append it twice.

Comment: ... it appears that appendChild is governing this behavior ....`it is removed from the current node`